# Library and Book Class, Constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

Why is the constructor not reading the elements in the array of the library class?

When I call an element let's say `csBooks[3]`, I get garbage.

```
public class Library {

     String address;
     public static Book[] bookLibrary = {};


      public Library(String location, Book[] s){

        address = location;

          for(int i = 0; i < bookLibrary.length-1; i++){

                bookLibrary[i] = s[i];
              }





     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries
       Book [] books = {new Book("The Da Vinci Code"),
                        new Book("Le Petit Prince"),
                        new Book("A Tale of Two Cities"),
                        new Book("The Lord of the Rings")};

        Book [] csBooks = {new Book("Java for Dummies"),
                          new Book("Operating Systems"),
                          new Book("Data Structures in Java"),
                          new Book("The Lord of the Rings")};



          Library firstLibrary = new Library("535 W114th St.", books);
          Library secondLibrary = new Library("1214 Amsterdam Av.", csBooks);


    }
}
```

This is the Book Class:

```
public class Book {

    String title;
    boolean borrowed;

    // Creates a new Book
    public Book(String bookTitle) {
        //Implement this method
    title = bookTitle;
    borrowed = false;
    }

    // Marks the book as rented
    public void borrowed() {
        //Implement this method
    borrowed = true;
    }

    // Set the book to borrowed
    public void rented() {
    //Implement this method
    borrowed = true;
    }

    // Marks the book as not rented
    public void returned() {
    //Implement this method
    borrowed = false;
    }

    // Returns true if the book is rented, false otherwise
    public boolean isBorrowed() {
    //Implement this method
    if(borrowed){
      return true;
    } else {
                  return false;
    }
    }

    // Returns the title of the book
    public String getTitle() {
    //Implement this method
    return title;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that `bookLibrary` is supposed to hold the Library's inventory, ie the books that are in there. In that case, it'll have to be non-static, since you want it to store different things for each instance of the class (library).

The second problem is that you create your `bookLibrary`-Array empty. An array that can store a total of 0 elements (books) will not be able to store the four elements you try to write into it. Even more so, since you're iterating based on bookLibrary's length. So, you'll have to properly set up the bookLibrary array in the constructor along the lines of `bookLibrary=new Book[s.length];`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong in several parts - at least, you have a static field.

However, to answer your "why isn't it reading" question, look at this part:

```
public Library(String location, Book[] s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < bookLibrary.length-1; i++){
        bookLibrary[i] = s[i];
    }
}
```

`bookLibrary.length - 1` is equal to `-1` during the constructor call and the loop will not iterate at all.

Probably, it should be `s.length` like this?

```
public Library(String location, Book[] s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        bookLibrary[i] = s[i];
    }
}
```

And why is it `-1`? It will not affect the last element.

*P.S.* I am not good at Java - I am a C# developer. Probably, it is a language issue, but why aren't you able to do (assuming that `bookLibrary` is not static anymore):

```
public Library(String location, Book[] s) {
    bookLibrary = s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because

```
public static Book[] bookLibrary = {};
```

is shared between two instances.
it should not be static.